# when using snapshot.key it gives me the child name in javascript firebase

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

**Problem**

When running snapshot.key instead of giving me the snapshot key it gives me a child name

heres my database

[database](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b8X27.png)

so for this example if I type in `snapshot.key` it gives me followingPeople instead of `-LT0ObbvApjBYmkGx4kh`

heres my code

```
firebase.database().ref().child("followingPeople").orderByChild("5lVdoINmfDd9DRTu29aHyfIbePn1").equalTo("bZsdMeJoWcfxKlXhcqITa0TgTNv1").on("value", function(snapshot) {

    console.log(snapshot.key)
})
```

Thanks,

Arnav

Comment: have you tried `snapshot.val()` ?

Comment: @eag845 yep and it showed me the snapshot.val() as expected but snapshot.key does not show me the snapshot key

Comment: and `console.log(Object.keys(snapshot.val()))` ?

Answer (score 0):

This is the expected behavior.  Your query could potentially match multiple children, and if that were the case, what would you expect for the single `key` property on the single snapshot you're given?  You see "followingPeople" here because that's where your query is rooted, and all of the matched children.

If you want the matched child keys, iterate the children of the given snapshot with [forEach](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.database.DataSnapshot#forEach), then log *those* snapshot keys to see key values like `-LT0ObbvApjBYmkGx4kh`.